# Error when submitting training job to gcloud

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am new to training on Google Cloud.

When I am running the training job, I get the following error:

```
(gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) Could not copy [research/dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz] to [training/packages/c5292b23e57f357dc2d63baab473c04337dbadd2deeb10965e743cd8422b964f/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: Not Found
```

I am using this to run the training job

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training job1 \     
--job-dir=gs://${ml-project-neu}/training \
--packages research/dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,research/slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
--module-name object_detection.train \
--config cloud.yml \
--runtime-version=1.4
-- \
--train_dir=gs://${ml-project-neu}/training \
--pipeline_config_path=gs://${ml-project-neu}/data/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure ${ml-poject-neu} is valid (it may be the empty string in your case); Make sure gs://${ml-project-neu} exists. And make sure the credentials you are using with gcloud have access to your GCS bucket (consider running gcloud auth login).

Comment: ml-project-neu is my bucket name. I verified it but the error is still there. Not sure how should I proceed.

Comment: Do you mind hard-coding the string "ml-project-neu" instead of using environment variables, e.g.

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training job1 \     
--job-dir=gs://ml-project-neu/training \
--packages research/dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,research/slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
--module-name object_detection.train \
--config cloud.yml \
--runtime-version=1.4
-- \
--train_dir=gs://ml-project-neu/training \
--pipeline_config_path=gs://ml-project-neu/data/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config

Comment: @OkDroid consider accepting the answer if it helped you